# How do I sort merged cells linked with other data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I'm making an inventory excel and I'm trying to sort these orders by state. However, some orders have multiple items and thus, I merged the state because 1) better viewing and 2) When I add up the orders/states I don't want to skew the data with multiples since there was technically only one order that went to said state.

How do I sort it with something like the NJ order with multiple items?

Here is what the sheet looks like so far.

```
 4379   Charles       Red                      CT   4/3/2014

 4381   II            Navy   Natural Raffia    CA   4/3/2014

 4382   Fen Chart     white  map               NY   4/4/2014

 4383   Desk          Black                    CT   4/4/2014

 4384   West Coffee   Navy   Natural Raffia    NJ   4/4/2014
        Edgar side    Navy   Natural Raffia     
        South Game    Navy   Glass          

 4385   Tini          Navy   Natural Raffia    CT   4/4/2014
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not order/filter by something that miss. 
Thus, you need to populate the state (and the other parameters which need such sorting) on every row. Then you may sort and filter by it.